# GenericType <T> passed to WEB-API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

So i have a method

```
[HttpGet('api/xxx/xxxx/xxx')
public HttpResponseMessage DoMyWork<T>(T obj)
{
}
```

Is it possible to pass the type to the call? if so how?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
 public async Task<T> DoMyWork<T>(T obj)
 {
   using(var client = new HttpClient())
   {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
   }
 }
```

It depends on what you're calling.

Comment: Add the `async` please.